# loading Div doesn't hide when load() finishes when function is called from parent object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the next code for loading content from an external html dynamically based on the class of the object (like filters).

```
    $('.item1').click(function(){
    $('.splash').hide(0);
    $('#content').delay(50).fadeIn(600);
    $('#loading').show();
    $('#products').load('products.html .typeofproducts',function () {
        $('#loading').hide(0);
        $('#products').fadeIn(500);
    });
});

<div id="wrapper">
      <div id="splash">
        <span class="item1">item1</span>
        <span class="item2">item2</span>
        <span class="item3">item3</span>
      </div>
      <div id="content" class="hidden">
        <div class="col floatleft" id="menu">
          <span class="item1">item1</span>
          <span class="item2">item2</span>
          <span class="item3">item3</span>
        </div>
        <div id="loading" class="hidden"><img src="loading.gif"></div>
        <div class="col floatleft" id="products">
         <!--load content here-->
        </div>
      </div>  
    </div>
```

When I call the function from `".item1"` within the `"#splash"`, the content loads without problem, but the loading gif, doesn't hide... but when i call the function from `".item1"` within the `"#content>#menu"` all the function works perfectly and the loading div hides.

Could someone help me, please? This is my first attempt at loading content dynamically.

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle?

Comment: I don't know if it's like this in your actual code or not, but you have id="splash" in your html, but a class ".splash" in your jquery.

Comment: Thanks @BenL. I had it wrong here, it wasn't my actual code, just a simplified version.

Comment: Glad you got your answer, I made this so might as well post it here for future. http://jsfiddle.net/n98Latk5/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `$('#loading').hide(0);` use `$('#loading').hide();`

OR you can hide it after complete

```
$('#products').load('products.html .typeofproducts',function () {
        $('#products').fadeIn(500);
    }).done(function() {
     $('#loading').hide();
  });
```

Comment: Thanks @Bhavin, I had it wrong, I just switched to hide(); and it worked perfectly!

Answer (score -1):

Change this:

```js
$('.splash').hide(0);
```

with this:

```
$('#splash').hide(0);
```

Comment: Please try to understand the problem before posting so you don't post a solution that doesn't solve it.